# Adding HTML to PHP loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using the following code to output a list of custom taxonomies:

```
<?php   // Get terms for post
    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'status' );
    // Loop over each item since it's an array
    if ( $terms != null ){
        foreach( $terms as $term ) {
            // Print the name method from $term which is an OBJECT
            print $term->slug ;
            print $term->name;
            // Get rid of the other data stored in the object, since it's not needed
            unset($term);
        }
    } 
?>
```

My question is, how can I add html to this loop? I have tried multiple methods such as:

```
echo '<button class="filter $term->slug" data-filter="$term->slug">$term->name</button>';
```

...but this either errors out, or doesn't print the required terms. My desired output of html would be:

```
<button class="filter term-slug" data-filter="term-slug">term-name</button>
```

Comment: echo should work. Can you show an example of how you tried to do this using echo?

Comment: @jerodev thanks for your comment. I have updated my answer. It outputs the html and outputs the terms as static text, it doesn't action them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this way. It should work. You need to just print `'".$term->name."'`like this inside the HTML to identify the object variable.

```
 <?php   // Get terms for post
        $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'status' );
        // Loop over each item since it's an array
        if ( $terms != null ){
            foreach( $terms as $term ) {
                // Print the name method from $term which is an OBJECT



          echo '<button class="filter "'.$term->slug.'"" data-filter="'.$term->slug.'">'".$term->name."'</button>';

                // Get rid of the other data stored in the object, since it's not needed
                unset($term);
            }
        } 
    ?>
```

Comment: Fix your quotes please.

Comment: @u_mulder, I have fixed my quotes. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your help :-)

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your line as below:-

```
echo "<button class='filter {$term->slug}' data-filter='{$term->slug}'>$term->name</button>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add below code and check.

```
<?php 
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'status' );
if ( $terms != null )
{
    foreach( $terms as $term )
    {
        echo '<button class="filter "'.$term->slug.'"" data-filter="'.$term->slug.'">'".$term->name."'</button>';
        unset($term);
    }
} 
?>
```